# Vertical alignment and spacing for two divs

Tags: html, css, fullscreen, vertical-alignment

I'm stuck with a vertical align issue. I have 2 divs. First one has auto height (depends on the browser size), the other one has fixed height and is positioned at the bottom of page. Also, the second div needs margin.

An exact example of what I want to do:

http://img199.imageshack.us/img199/9569/79106387.jpg

I tried:

```
<html>
<body>
<style>
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body { background: #a7daf6; }
</style>

<div style="width:200px; height:100%; position:absolute; background:#000; opacity:0.6"> </div>

<div style="width:200px; height:40px; position:absolute; background:#eee; bottom:0; opacity:0.6"> </div>

</body>
</html>
```

but I can't give margin to second div. Any ideas?

Comment: The question must have disappeared somehow?

Comment: what do you expect to see when you apply `margin-top`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can simply apply to the first `<div>` this style: `top:-42px`.

If you need content inside the `<div>`, you can add another `<div>` with `padding-top: 42px`.

Like this:

[***Live Demo***](http://jsbin.com/avafa3)

```
<div style="width:200px; height:100%; position:absolute; background:#000; opacity:0.6; top:-42px">
    <div style="padding-top:42px; color:#fff">hello</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

try to add this for first div:

```
<div style="width:200px; position:absolute; top:0px; bottom: 42px; background:#000; opacity:0.6"> </div>
```

and remove `margin-top` from second one

Answer (score 0):

Giving any element an absolute position will remove it from the flow of the document.
Not matter what the margin is other elements will not be affected.